# Can the off-topic close description please be corrected?

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions

I closed a question and was greeted with this message:

[image: Close message]

Can those empty references please be corrected? It should probably say:

> Questions on SharePoint are expected to generally
>   relate to SharePoint, within the scope defined in the faq.

Comment: Questions on **SharePoint** are expected to generally relate to **SharePoint**????

Comment: @KitMenke: `String.Format("Questions on {0} are expected to generally relate to {1}...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was from a missing database entry when the site was configured. It has been fixed (although it may still display incorrectly for a short time due to caching).